# Docker compose ignores my Dockerfile when I use the build command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this folder structure:

/home/me/composetest
/home/me/composetest/mywildflyimage

Inside composites I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
    image: test/mywildfly
    container_name: wildfly
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "9990:9990"
```

Inside mywildflyimage I have this docker image:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly

EXPOSE 8080 9990

ADD standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent 
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

If i run

```
docker built -t test/mywildfly .
docker-compose up
```

Everything works great, and the management part is minded to 0.0.0.0 (-bmanagement 0.0.0.0 part of the CMD command).

If I change my docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
        build: mywildflyimage
        container_name: wildfly
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "9990:9990"
```

and run
    docker-compose up

It still boots, but the admin part is not bound to 0.0.0.0 anymore (this is the default behaviour for the image I inherited from).

Why does it stop working when I use the `build` command in the docker-compose.ml?

EDIT: It seems that it is ignoring all my docker file commands.

Comment: Did you run `docker-compose build` after changing docker-comopse.yml file? and then `docker-compose up`

Comment: No, I didn't and it solved my problem. could you please change it to an answer so I can mark it as answer, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

run `docker-compose build` after changing docker-comopse.yml and then `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 4):

Before you type `docker-compose up`, you should build images with `docker-compose build [options] [SERVICE...]`.

```
Options:
--force-rm  Always remove intermediate containers.
--no-cache  Do not use cache when building the image.
--pull      Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
```

In your case, ex: `docker-compose build --no-cache web`