# Why is docker-compose ignoring changes to the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have made changes in my Dockerfile and yet when I run either

```
docker-compose up
dock-compose rm && docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

an old image is used, as the shown steps states are outdated.

I specifically tell it to build the container in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
my-app:
    build: ./
    hostname: my-app
    ...
```

Yet when I build the container just via docker:

```
docker build .
```

The right container is built. What am I missing? I have tried [this to no avail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023697/docker-compose-ignores-my-dockerfile-when-i-use-the-build-command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what dockerfile is configured in your `docker-compose.yml`.

My app has *two* dockerfiles, and docker-compose used a different one than docker itself, as it should:

```
my-app:
    build: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
```

Adapting that dockerfile as well fixed the problem.

And, oh, if you are using multiple dockerfiles, it's nice to add that in the project's documentation.

Comment: k0pernikus do you have double personality?

Comment: @Drumnbass Just because I like talking to myself? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question but my answer was different.

I moved from a large nginx image to a slim, Alpine nginx image.

I thought `docker compose` was ignoring my Dockerfile as the error looked like it had not copied a script.  The error was:

`/bin/sh: /usr/bin/start.sh: not found`

Well, the file was there.  The file had the correct permissions.  All I needed to do was to resolve the wrong shebang in my script and all worked with `docker-compose`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh              WORKED

#!/bin/bash            FAILED
```